# how do i get a random double within a specified range?

Tags: java, random, double, range

I really thought this would work, but when I ran it, I always get some random huge decimal and it makes no sense. The logic is right, so why doesn't the code work?

```
do{
  value = rnd.nextDouble();
}while(value>min && value<max);
```

Keep in mind "min" and "max" are actually functions that do some simple arithmetic operations then return that value, but I just put min and max for simplicity so I don't have to post the entire class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a `start` and `end` variables (`int` or `double`), and use `nextDouble()` like:

```
value = rnd.nextDouble() * (end - start) + start;
```

Remember that:

> **public double nextDouble()**
>   Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed double value between 0.0 and 1.0 from this random number generator's sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The [`nextDouble` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28%29) returns a random `double` value between `0.0` inclusive, and `1.0` exclusive.  You can translate the range by adding the `min` value and scale the range up by multiplying it by the difference between `max` and `min`.

```
value = (rnd.nextDouble() * (max - min)) + min;
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate a random value between `rangeMin` and `rangeMax`:

```
 Random r = new Random();
 double randomValue = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble();
```